# Is there an IDE that highlights possible logical errors? If so, what is the best?

Tags: javascript, ide, logical-operators, error-logging

For example, after spending an hour on the following javascript logic error, I finally realized the problem. Keep in mind that this if statement is embedded in a lot of other code.

```
for(i=0;i<alength;i++)
{
    if(myvar = correct)
    {
        //ommitted irrelevent code            
    }
}
```

As you know, I was assigning the correct variable to myvar as well as comparing it, so it should have been:

```
if(myvar == correct)
```

After finally realizing the error, I was very annoyed that I didn't recognize it much faster. I have been programming for over 5 years, mostly in java, but this happens quite often and I was wondering if there is an IDE or something that can highlight possible logical errors.

Comment: This question can be answered by giving you a written bible with programming errors. That is considered a little too broad though. Experience and a good IDE can solve those things.

Comment: For the particular problem: C++ compiler issues a warning if assignment is not enclosed with additional parenthesis.

Comment: If it's a compiled language then enable the compiler's 'treat warnings as errors' flag. Use lint. Have the code peer-reviewed. Reduce the length of sections of code (by moving code into functions etc) to make code-reading simpler and code review more likely to catch errors.

Comment: There's a billion common programming errors. A community wiki type of question, for a specific language, with one answer being one common error, might work better.

Comment: The question has been modified and both the current question and even the original question have been answered by jarmod and TheShellfishMeme with others suggesting a good IDE. I'm sure that there are more answers that could be helpful, so downvoting does not seem applicable and I think the question should be taken off hold. However, I don't care about the negative points. I care about the much appreciated help from this awesome site, StackOverflow and its awesome users. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Mat, this question has been modified. Can you take a look to see if it can be re-opened? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your code linted by [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).
There should be plugins for any major editors.

In this case, it would have told you "Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment."